# c# .NET Example of using JWT OAUTH flow with salesforce

Tags: oauth2, c#, .net, auth

Does anyone have an example of the JWT oauth implementation in c#?

Thanks

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=5

Comment: That documentation page goes over the steps required to generate the token (it's above the example implementation in Java), which is in fairly plain language. Have you tried following those steps? If not, have you tried searching for a package/wrapper/whatever for OAuth in C#?

Comment: jwt.io lists .NET implementations, recommend you use one of those.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe a bit late, but recently I came across the same requirement and rolled my own implementation.

Youn could find it here: [ForceDotNetJwtCompanion on github](https://github.com/claboran/ForceDotNetJwtCompanion)

Brief description of the implementation:

1. Implementation of JWT Payload [see Salesforce Java Example](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=5)

```csharp
public class JwtPayload
    {
        [JsonProperty("iss")]
        public string Iss { get; set; } //Client Id of the Connected App
        [JsonProperty("sub")]
        public string Sub { get; set; } // Salesforce username
        [JsonProperty("aud")]
        public string Aud { get; set; } // Authorization Server URL
        [JsonProperty("exp")]
        public string Exp { get; set; } Expiration = now + 3min in sec
        public string ConvertToBase64() => CommonHelpers
            .UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this)));
    }
```

1. Create JWT and sign it

```csharp
// Based on BouncyCastle [BouncyCastle C#][3]
    public class PasswordFinder : IPasswordFinder
    {
        private readonly string _password;

        public PasswordFinder(string password)
        {
            _password = password;
        }
        
        public char[] GetPassword() => _password.ToCharArray();
    }
  
        public static byte[] CreateSignature(PrivateKeyWrapper privateKeyWrapper, byte[] bytesToSign)
        {
            var sig = SignerUtilities.GetSigner("SHA" + 256 + "withRSA");
            sig.Init(
                true, 
                new RsaKeyParameters(
                    true, 
                    privateKeyWrapper.Modulus, 
                    privateKeyWrapper.Exponent
                    )
                );
            sig.BlockUpdate(bytesToSign, 0, bytesToSign.Length);
            return sig.GenerateSignature();
        }

        public static PrivateKeyWrapper CreatePrivateKeyWrapperWithPassPhrase(string key, string passphrase)
        {
            var pemReader = new PemReader(new StringReader(key), new PasswordFinder(passphrase));
            var pem = (AsymmetricCipherKeyPair) pemReader.ReadObject();
            var param = (RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters) pem.Private;
            return new PrivateKeyWrapper
            {
                Modulus = param.Modulus, 
                Exponent = param.Exponent
            };
        }

    public class Jwt
    {
        // Salesforce supports RS256 
        private const string Header = "{\"alg\": \"RS256\"}";
        private JwtPayload _jwtPayload;
        private string _consumerKey; // aka ClientId
        private string _tokenEndpoint;
        private string _subject; // Salesforce user
        private string _expiration;
        private readonly PrivateKeyWrapper _privateKeyWrapper;

        private Jwt(PrivateKeyWrapper privateKeyWrapper)
        {
            _privateKeyWrapper = privateKeyWrapper;
        }

        public static Jwt CreateJwt(PrivateKeyWrapper privateKeyWrapper) => new Jwt(privateKeyWrapper);

        public Jwt AddConsumerKey(string consumerKey)
        {
            _consumerKey = consumerKey;
            return this;
        }

        public Jwt AddTokenEndpoint(string tokenEndpoint)
        {
            _tokenEndpoint = tokenEndpoint;
            return this;
        }

        public Jwt AddSubject(string subject)
        {
            _subject = subject;
            return this;
        }

        public Jwt AddExpiration(DateTime now)
        { 
            _expiration = JwtHelpers.CreateExpTimeAsString(now);
            return this;
        }

        public string Build()
        {
            if (
                string.IsNullOrEmpty(_consumerKey) ||
                string.IsNullOrEmpty(_expiration) ||
                string.IsNullOrEmpty(_subject) ||
                string.IsNullOrEmpty(_tokenEndpoint) 
                ) throw new ArgumentException("Missing arguments for JWT!");
            
            _jwtPayload = new JwtPayload
            {
                Aud = _tokenEndpoint,
                Exp = _expiration,
                Iss = _consumerKey,
                Sub = _subject
            };
            var bytesToSign = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
                string.Join(".", 
                    CommonHelpers.UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Header)), 
                    _jwtPayload.ConvertToBase64())
                );
            return string
                .Join(".", 
                    CommonHelpers.UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Header)), 
                    _jwtPayload.ConvertToBase64(),
                    CommonHelpers.UrlEncode(KeyHelpers.CreateSignature(_privateKeyWrapper, bytesToSign))
                    );
        }
    }
```

3. Send JWT to the Authorization Endpoint

```csharp
var request = new HttpRequestMessage
            {
                Method = HttpMethod.Post,
                RequestUri = new Uri(https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token"),
                Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("assertion", jwt)
                })
            };
responseMessage = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead);
```