# Access Named Credential using C#

Tags: namedcredentials

Is it possible to access the Named Credential using C#? We have an integration with the other system where the external system will be consuming our custom API and someone from our team suggest to use Named Credential. I'm not sure if that's doable. I only knew we can use such configuration within Salesforce. Any reference will greatly help. Thanks!

Comment: A Named Credential is for calling out from Salesforce, you're right. For inbound calls, the type of authorization depends on many factors. Here's one approach: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/271508/c-net-example-of-using-jwt-oauth-flow-with-salesforce

Comment: Thanks @identigral for the confirmation.